# Gzip decompress throws EOFException

Tags: java, gzip, eofexception

I am currently trying to decompress a byte array by using gzip decompress, however, I receive an EOFException, can anyone help me with this error ? Thanks

this is my codes:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] payload = new byte[] {
           (byte)0x1F, (byte)0x8B, (byte)0x08, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x75, (byte)0x92, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0x68, (byte)0x1C, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x10, (byte)0xC7, (byte)0x27, (byte)0x97,
           (byte)0xA4, (byte)0xBD, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x92, (byte)0xDE, (byte)0x36, (byte)0xB1, (byte)0x4D, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0xD4, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0x88, (byte)0x1E, (byte)0x97, (byte)0xDE, (byte)0x8F, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0xA1, 
           (byte)0x69, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x17, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x68, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x31, (byte)0xA8, (byte)0xCD, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0xDE, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0x39, (byte)0x88, (byte)0x77, (byte)0xC9, 
           (byte)0xDB, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x70, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0x1F, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0x42, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x2C, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x4D, (byte)0x4A, (byte)0x4D, (byte)0xAD, (byte)0xB6, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x16, (byte)0x7D, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0x52, 
           (byte)0x44, (byte)0x41, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x5B, (byte)0x6A, (byte)0x11, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x84, (byte)0x8A, (byte)0x4A, (byte)0xD4, (byte)0xEC, (byte)0x46, (byte)0x11, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x51, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x42, 
           (byte)0x2C, (byte)0x35, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xBC, (byte)0xB7, (byte)0x77, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x44, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0x67, (byte)0x58, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0xF3, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0xCE, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0xDB, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0xE0, 
           (byte)0x5C, (byte)0xCF, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0xD2, (byte)0xC0, (byte)0xCF, (byte)0x0A, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0xDD, (byte)0x50, (byte)0xF3, (byte)0xD7, (byte)0x92, (byte)0x8C, (byte)0x91, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0x3F, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0xAD, 
           (byte)0xA7, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0x2A, (byte)0xE6, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0x58, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x5F, (byte)0x25, (byte)0x7A, (byte)0x8B, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0xB0, (byte)0x20, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0xBD, (byte)0xD0, (byte)0xA6, 
           (byte)0x41, (byte)0x13, (byte)0x1B, (byte)0xEF, (byte)0x7E, (byte)0x89, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0xE5, (byte)0x5B, (byte)0x1F, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x2B, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0x2C, (byte)0x0C, (byte)0x9A, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0xAC, (byte)0xE9, (byte)0x8B, 
           (byte)0x27, (byte)0x92, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0x80, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x55, (byte)0xC2, (byte)0x3A, (byte)0x8C, (byte)0xCE, (byte)0xA0, (byte)0x8A, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x68, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x0B, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x3C, 
           (byte)0x4B, (byte)0x0D, (byte)0x4B, (byte)0x25, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0x31, (byte)0xEC, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x49, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x36, (byte)0x08, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0x1E, (byte)0xDD, (byte)0xA8, (byte)0xB0, (byte)0x36, 
           (byte)0xA0, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x4D, (byte)0x58, (byte)0xAD, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x5C, (byte)0x15, (byte)0xD6, (byte)0x6A, (byte)0x74, (byte)0xBE, (byte)0x11, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0x3A, (byte)0x3A, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0x0A, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0x03, 
           (byte)0x3A, (byte)0x17, (byte)0x05, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0x8C, (byte)0xCE, (byte)0x25, (byte)0xC1, (byte)0x3F, (byte)0x56, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0x33, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x6A, (byte)0x82, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0x44, (byte)0x37, (byte)0x29, (byte)0xF3, 
           (byte)0x6E, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0xA1, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0x5B, (byte)0x58, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0x74, (byte)0xD3, (byte)0x4A, (byte)0x2D, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x5D, (byte)0x1A, (byte)0xAC, (byte)0x24, (byte)0xC7, (byte)0x13, 
           (byte)0xE4, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0x4C, (byte)0x39, (byte)0x16, (byte)0x86, (byte)0x8B, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0x0A, (byte)0x79, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x0A, (byte)0xB5, (byte)0xC2, (byte)0x5A, (byte)0x89, (byte)0x4E, (byte)0x44, (byte)0xC6, (byte)0x99, 
           (byte)0xF3, (byte)0x82, (byte)0x4F, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0x77, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x15, (byte)0x40, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0xC3, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0xC2, (byte)0x16, (byte)0x0D, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x91, (byte)0xC2, 
           (byte)0x3B, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0x15, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0x99, (byte)0xB5, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0xBE, (byte)0x61, (byte)0xB5, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xD4, (byte)0x08, (byte)0xEB, (byte)0x43, (byte)0x74, (byte)0xE7, 
           (byte)0x84, (byte)0xB5, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0x12, (byte)0xBD, (byte)0x4C, (byte)0x39, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x1A, (byte)0x34, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0x89, (byte)0xBE, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0xA8, (byte)0x3B, (byte)0x50, (byte)0xD9, (byte)0x38, 
           (byte)0x9C, (byte)0x28, (byte)0xEF, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x0B, (byte)0x5E, (byte)0x44, (byte)0xF7, (byte)0xAA, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xDB, (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x7D, (byte)0x4E, (byte)0xF0, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x8E, (byte)0x8B, 
           (byte)0xD1, (byte)0x2B, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x96, (byte)0xC4, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x25, (byte)0x74, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0x10, (byte)0xA3, (byte)0xD3, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x46, (byte)0xE7, (byte)0x71, (byte)0xB6, (byte)0x51,
           (byte)0x70, (byte)0x1F, (byte)0xCE, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x14, (byte)0x3C, (byte)0x84, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0x69, (byte)0xC1, (byte)0xEF, (byte)0xC1, (byte)0x59, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0xE2, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x16, (byte)0xBC, (byte)0x19, (byte)0xDD, 
           (byte)0x2F, (byte)0x05, (byte)0xEF, (byte)0x46, (byte)0xF7, (byte)0x82, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0x51, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x5F, (byte)0x15, (byte)0x3C, (byte)0x82, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x40, (byte)0x0D, (byte)0x56, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0x89, 
           (byte)0x83, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0x54, (byte)0xE6, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x43, (byte)0xB5, (byte)0xB0, (byte)0x3B, (byte)0x70, (byte)0xE6, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x61, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x33, (byte)0x3B, 
           (byte)0x84, (byte)0x75, (byte)0x51, (byte)0x46, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x81, (byte)0x88, (byte)0x06, (byte)0xB7, (byte)0x52, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x29, (byte)0xEA, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0x93, (byte)0x7D, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0xE4, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x76, 
           (byte)0xD8, (byte)0xF4, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x45, (byte)0xDB, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0xE1, (byte)0x4C, (byte)0x42, (byte)0xC5, (byte)0x66, (byte)0xE9, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xFA, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x65, 
           (byte)0xBF, (byte)0x91, (byte)0xC5, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0x75, (byte)0x92, (byte)0xCB, (byte)0x47, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0xAC, (byte)0x15, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0x49, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x40, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x74, (byte)0xD2, (byte)0xC2, 
           (byte)0x1E, (byte)0x40, (byte)0x87, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x0B, (byte)0x40, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x5B, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x47, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0xD4, (byte)0x52, (byte)0x5F, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0x67, (byte)0x47, (byte)0xF5, (byte)0xA3, 
           (byte)0xF4, (byte)0x8F, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0xFA, (byte)0x13, (byte)0x5D, (byte)0x3F, (byte)0xC7, (byte)0xCF, (byte)0xCB, (byte)0x7A, (byte)0x88, (byte)0xD9, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0xC4, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x7D, (byte)0x97, (byte)0x91,
           (byte)0x95, (byte)0x75, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x8C, (byte)0xC9, (byte)0xD4, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0xAA, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0x05, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0xD9, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x6E, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0xFA, 
           (byte)0x12, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0x9E, (byte)0x50, (byte)0xC0, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0x8F, (byte)0x5C, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0x01, (byte)0xAC, (byte)0x61, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0x93, (byte)0x37, (byte)0x81, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x02, (byte)0xDE,
           (byte)0x4A, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x68, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x60, (byte)0xCF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x2D, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0xB0, (byte)0x89, (byte)0xED, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0x1C, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xA0, (byte)0xC6, 
           (byte)0x36, (byte)0x2D, (byte)0x3B, (byte)0xE1, (byte)0xC5, (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x89, (byte)0xCD, (byte)0x7A, (byte)0xB0, (byte)0xCE, (byte)0x1B, (byte)0xB1, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x4D, (byte)0x9E, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0x52, (byte)0x4F,
           (byte)0x7A, (byte)0x71, (byte)0xEA, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x7A, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0xB1, (byte)0xB4, (byte)0x34, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x41, (byte)0xF5, (byte)0xA5, (byte)0x79, 
           (byte)0x73, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x97, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0x18, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0xA9, (byte)0xD3, (byte)0x05, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x27, (byte)0x10, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x07, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0xBE, 
           (byte)0x92, (byte)0x13, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0xD6, (byte)0xED, (byte)0x3C, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0xEA, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x24, (byte)0xF5, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0x7B, (byte)0xE9, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x84, (byte)0x01, (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x64, (byte)0xF0, 
           (byte)0x1D, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x01, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0x06, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x39, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0x5F, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0x4E, (byte)0x12, (byte)0xB7, (byte)0x03, (byte)0xC4, (byte)0x08, (byte)0xF9, 
           (byte)0x9E, (byte)0x90, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x37, (byte)0x91, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0x31, (byte)0xEB, (byte)0x01, (byte)0xE2, (byte)0xEC, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0x87, (byte)0x9E, (byte)0x20, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0x81, (byte)0xF2, (byte)0xD2, 
           (byte)0x29, (byte)0x8E, (byte)0xB1, (byte)0x54, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x16, (byte)0x57, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x82, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x72, (byte)0x4B, (byte)0x10, (byte)0x26, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0x16,
           (byte)0xA0, (byte)0xBC, (byte)0x87, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x03, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0xEA, (byte)0xEB, (byte)0x9E, (byte)0x26, (byte)0xE4, (byte)0x4E, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x24, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x84, (byte)0xD4, (byte)0x2F, 
           (byte)0x52, (byte)0x8A, (byte)0x79, (byte)0x33, (byte)0xBD, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xB9, (byte)0x1E, (byte)0xDC, (byte)0x4A, (byte)0x7B, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x68, (byte)0x27, (byte)0x6A, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0x51, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xB2, 
           (byte)0x50, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x49, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x5A, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x90, (byte)0xBD, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0xF7, (byte)0x93, (byte)0xBC, (byte)0x8C, (byte)0x1C, 
           (byte)0x39, (byte)0x4C, (byte)0xC7, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0xB7, (byte)0xCB, (byte)0x1F, (byte)0xE1, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0x05, (byte)0xDB, (byte)0x3C, (byte)0x93, (byte)0x48, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0x42, (byte)0x62, (byte)0x34,
           (byte)0xFC, (byte)0xBD, (byte)0xEC, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0x20, (byte)0x87, (byte)0x97, (byte)0x44, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0x90, (byte)0xDB, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0x33, (byte)0xF4, (byte)0xDC, (byte)0xA0, (byte)0x77, (byte)0xAA, (byte)0xA3,
           (byte)0x4D, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0x2B, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0xEA, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x2D, (byte)0x84, (byte)0xF5, (byte)0x13, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x57, (byte)0xC6, (byte)0x24, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0x38,
           (byte)0xA2, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x25, (byte)0xAD, (byte)0x1E, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x93, (byte)0x1D, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0xA0, (byte)0x47, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0x8E, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x37, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x1B, 
           (byte)0xF5, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x7B, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0x95, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0x08, (byte)0x98, (byte)0x93, (byte)0x2A, (byte)0x04, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0xD1, (byte)0xC6, (byte)0x08, (byte)0x42, (byte)0x05, (byte)0x1D, (byte)0xEA, (byte)0xD7, 
           (byte)0x83, (byte)0x07, (byte)0xD2, (byte)0x6A, (byte)0xBD, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0xE9, (byte)0xE4, (byte)0xF2, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0xB2, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0x64, (byte)0x0C, (byte)0x19, (byte)0x8A, (byte)0x38, (byte)0xDE, 
           (byte)0xAF, (byte)0x37, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x3C, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x8C, (byte)0x91, (byte)0x97, (byte)0x32, (byte)0xA9, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x4C, (byte)0xBC, (byte)0x06, (byte)0x60, (byte)0x3B,
           (byte)0x9B, (byte)0x74, (byte)0xE4, (byte)0x2D, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x5A, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0x68, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0x86, (byte)0x97, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0x8A, (byte)0x05};



        byte[] objectArr;
        try (ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload);
             GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
             ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            int size = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)size];
            int count;
            while ((count = gzipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            
            objectArr = outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(objectArr.length * 2);
        for (byte b : objectArr) {
            hex.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        System.out.println(hex.toString());
        
        String decodedString = new String(objectArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
}
```

I tested the to be decompressed byte array in c#, it worked ok, don't know why in Java it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gzip data is corrupted. There are two zero bytes missing at the end of `payload`. Add those, and there is no EOF error.

```
... (byte)0x8A, (byte)0x05, 0, 0};
```

Comment: You may want to figure out how your gzip data got corrupted in the first place.

Comment: Good one. How did you discover *what* the corruption consisted of?

Comment: I know the gzip format. After the deflate data ended there were six bytes. There is supposed to be an eight-byte gzip trailer. The last four bytes are supposed to be the uncompressed length in little-endian order. The length of the uncompressed data was 1418, less than 64K, so those last two bytes had to have been zeros.

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with that gzipped data.  When I wrote it to a file and then uncompressed it using `zcat` on Linux, the `zcat` command complained:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
```

Same with `gzip -d`.  But `gzip -l` says:

```
     compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
            979            92994711 100.0% data
```

Perhaps C# is tolerant of malformed (truncated) gzip files?

Perhaps you made a mistake in translating the `payload` array initializer to Java?

---

The other observation is that the partial uncompressed file doesn't look like proper UTF-8 anyway.  There are text strings in there, but much of it is unintelligible (or binary) data.

Comment: No, I think it's OK: `x.bin.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 92994711` (`file x.bin.gz`)

Comment: @g00se `file` does not tell you whether the file is correct or complete, it just reads a bit from the beginning of the file. Run `gzip -t` to check whether the file is error-free.

Comment: @g00se - That looks like what `gzip -l` says too.  Try actually uncompressing it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's true. But `zless` reads it fine. It's binary but contains *some* strings

Comment: @g00se I'm not concerned with the nature of its contents, only with whether it's valid or truncated: `file` does *not* tell you that.

Comment: I've already addressed the issue of `file`

Comment: `gzip -l` just looks at the last eight bytes to get the uncompressed length. It obviously got that very wrong, since gzip can't compress by a factor of ~100,000. See my answer.